# android distancebetween: really strange behaviour

Tags: android, gps

Something really strange happens there.

My app calculates the distance between two points stored in a text file:

```
Location.distanceBetween(lat1, long1, lat2, long2, res);
```

That's what I get, when I log the following:

```
Log.d(tag, "lat1: " + lat1 + ", long1: " + long1 + ", lat2: " + lat2 + ", long2: " + long2 + ", dist: " + res[0]);
```

Output on a sony smart phone:

```
lat1: 49.358788, long1: 7.25395, lat2: 49.358771, long2: 7.254031, dist: 6.180519
```

Output on a lenovo tablet:

```
lat1: 49.358788, long1: 7.25395, lat2: 49.358771, long2: 7.254031, dist: 110.74074
```

As you can see the distance is very different. But why???

A timer is running calculating the distance between two points every second. Most calculations are ok but some of them are absolutely wrong.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: There's a lot. What do you want to see?

Comment: I found this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41911   Is there really a problem with using Location.distanceBetween?

Comment: I guess the android version differs on the two devices? what happens if you run them over the exact same code? copy/paste the source into your project, see what happens: `http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android/location/Location.java`

Comment: You're right, the android versions are different ont the two devices. And sorry, there is no code behind your link: Unknown identifier: "android/location/Location.java". Falling back to search"

Comment: I've been seeing the same issue when the code runs with Robolectric. The issue with CyanogenMod link above was related to the ARM instructions. Since robolectric runs tests in JVM, can it be related to that as well. I don't know how to fix it though.